# Number of Rogue Talents at level 10?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, rogue, unchained

Do you get 1 or 2 rogue talents/advanced talents at level 10 of the unchained rogue?

If 2, can you use both for advanced talents?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Just the One

[*Unchained Rogue's Advanced Talents*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/rogue-unchained/#TOC-Advanced-Talents) says this:

> At 10th level and every 2 levels thereafter, a rogue can choose [an] advanced talent **in place of a rogue talent**. *(emphasis mine)*

So this gives you the option of choosing from a separate set of talents, but does not grant any further talents.

So your gain in talents for your advancement to 10th level is **one talent, advanced or regular**.